# query private chat participants query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I created a Private chat
my database looks like this

```
+----+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | msg                                  | user_id | receiver_user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | In dui magna posuere                 |       1 |                2 | 2016-03-27 11:50:25 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Sed a libero                         |       1 |                2 | 2016-03-27 11:50:41 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  3 | Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus |       3 |                1 | 2016-03-27 11:51:09 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Aenean leo ligula                    |       4 |                1 | 2016-03-27 16:13:32 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to get a list of my chat participants,

So if I'm user id 1, my participants are 2,3,4

if I'm user id 4 my participants are 1

I'm not sure how to go about it.
I'm on laravel 5.2. but I think this will require a raw query.

Comment: Don't know laravel syntax, but basically `select user_id from t where receiver_user_id = <YourId> UNION select receiver_user_id from t where user_id = <YourID>`

Comment: Does the job, Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I you are interested, this is how it looks in laravel
`$users = PM::select('user_id')
            ->where('receiver_user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->union(PM::select('receiver_user_id')->where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = PM::select('user_id')
->where('receiver_user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)
->union(PM::select('receiver_user_id')->where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id));
```

Added it to the answers so that it won't show up in unanswered questions.